# The preLaunchTask 'C/C++:g++.exe build active file' terminated with exit code -1. while running c++ file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, mingw

the code is just hello world printing nothing else.

those are the files in .vscode:

launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/path/to/gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
                    "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }

    ]
}
```

tasks.json:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

i searched for solutions but they didn't work. The .exe file is not showing now (and when it was showing i had the same problem so it's not a big change)

also, when i had the .exe file, it worked by calling it from the terminal only, but then stopped from working.

Comment: `launch.json` is for setting up the debugger. If you just want to run the program, I would recommend finding another extension to do it for you, or just invoking it manually. It also appears that you did not install minGW via MSYS2. That means the likelihood that you made a mistake is >0. Enough so that I recommend throwing your environment out and doing it the proper way. I get to say it's proper because it's in the [official documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw).

Comment: @sweenish c++ used to works always. then a couple days ago i had to delete vscode then reinstall it because of other problems, so c++ stopped working

Comment: One shouldn't affect the other, and VS Code has never broken itself so hard that I have ever needed to reinstall it. My initial comment still stands. When it comes to what might be specifically wrong in your case, maybe you didn't configure the extension properly. Who knows? What I do know is that Microsoft themselves have a page that outlines the method they recommend for setting up minGW for use with VS Code. What's your reasoning for not wanting to do it their way?

Comment: @sweenish well i did install it their way before should i try installing minGW again?

Comment: It could even be as simple as you opening a file and not a folder.

Comment: Did you? The path provided for g++ says otherwise. Packages installed by MSYS2 live in C:\msys64\ by default. Your compiler doesn't have msys64 in its path.